# More than one row as result

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure that I made to basically transfer the values from one of the two columns "**not_good** and **good**" to the column "**comment**" in the same table using the **grade** value:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_comments()
BEGIN

DECLARE var INT;
SELECT grade INTO var FROM table2;

    IF (var <= 7) THEN
        UPDATE table2 set comment = not_good;
    ELSE
        UPDATE table2 set comment = good;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I `CALL add_comentarios();` I receive the following error:

```
#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row
```

Can't figure out how to make it work as I want

PS: I'm a begginer rsrs

Thanks a lot for any answer!

Comment: What you declared PROCEDURE name?and which PROCEDURE are you calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT X INTO Y` queries are only valid for single result queries; since your query selects from the whole table, it would only be valid if the table had a single row. What you are trying to do can be done with a single query anyway....

```
UPDATE table2 
SET comment = CASE WHEN grade <= 7 THEN 'not_good' ELSE 'good' END
;
```

Answer (score 0):

**select** clause fetch multiple records at one time so your query like this

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE add_comment() BEGIN declare var int; SELECT grade INTO var FROM table2 limit 1; if(var <= 7) then update table2 set comment = 'not_good'; else update table2 set comment = 'good'; END IF; END$$
```

after call the procedure which created `CALL add_comment();`